# ProgressBar is not coming fine with support library v13:24.1.1 android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have updated Android studio recently to build tools 24.0.0 and added support library **com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1** in gradle file.
But the progress bar for which I am using the below code is not working in Lollipop version 5.1, API 22.

```
            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/filterProgress"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

It is coming like below image in Lollipop.

[image]

How can I resolve this in Lollipop, please tell me if anyone know about this issue. 
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I remember some problems with this attribute, can you do a test and check the explicit style "@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar" instead?

Comment: I have used this attribute instead of this **style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"**, but it is giving grey color progress bar in Lollipop instead of the material design progress bar.